# PHP - Little MySQL space and needs to store a decent amount of data. Opinions on my method of coping

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the situation. I am writing a cms for a high school sports team (Track and Field) to show results. So, this database will gain data regularly.

What I planned on doing was using a MySQL database to as an "index" to say.
For Ex:

```
-------------------------
| id | url | file       |
-------------------------
| 0  | name | 2ef42sdf  |
-------------------------
| 1  | meet | dj4ld34g  |
-------------------------
```

I would read the text file, unserialize the data into a PHP array, and loop through.

My other option would be to just store the serialized data in the table itself. My issue here is the amount of athletes (varies) and their places, times, splits, etc, could get kind of large.

I was wondering what is the best idea considering that the MySQL database I have has a size limit of 1GB and file system has a limit of 100GB. Anyone have any ideas another way to handle little MySQL space? Did you have an issue like this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1GB is actually a vast quantity of non-binary data.  How big is each record?  How many rows do you expect to have?  You can do straightforward math here to decide how long 1GB will last you.

Comment: well...if the file system has 100GB for you, than MySQL also has that. IF there is some strange restriction on MySQL, use SQLite, it is a file, and behaves as a single file as far as the OS cares.